# How to load and show adx anchoredadaptivead in flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

I want to show adx anchoredadaptivead ads in flutter Android and iOS both.

I use mobile ads plugin but it's not working please give me any solution.

I use mobile ads plugin but I want to show Ad Manager ads.use loader to when ad load then loader hide and show ad but ads not load and loader not hide.i already put appid in my mainfest file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its very easy

try this to load Google Ad manager ads.

1. [Use google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)

For Load Ad

```
AdManagerBannerAd? _anchoredAdaptiveAd;
bool _isLoaded = false;

Future<void> _loadAd() async {
    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size =
        await AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.truncate());

    if (size == null) {
      return;
    }

    _anchoredAdaptiveAd = AdManagerBannerAd(
      adUnitId: // your adID,
      request: const AdManagerAdRequest(),
      listener: AdManagerBannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          setState(() {
            _anchoredAdaptiveAd = ad as AdManagerBannerAd?;
            _isLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
      sizes: [size],
    );
    return _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.load();
  }
```

For Show Ad

```
SafeArea(
              bottom: true,
              child: Center(
                child: _anchoredAdaptiveAd != null && _isLoaded
                    ? SizedBox(
                        width: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.sizes[0].width.toDouble(),
                        height: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.sizes[0].height.toDouble(),
                        child: AdWidget(ad: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ),
            ),
```

For Dispose Ad

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _anchoredAdaptiveAd?.dispose();
    rewardedAd?.dispose();
  }
```